# How sqlite to do a range of avg by different group

Tags: sqlite

I have a table and value like ,

```
        name    date          score
----------------------------------------
1.      Mary   2017-03-01     14
2.      John   2017-03-01     22
3.      Tom    2017-03-01     6
4.      Mary   2017-03-02     35
5.      John   2017-03-02     17
6.      Tom    2017-03-02     50
7.      Mary   2017-03-03     90
8.      John   2017-03-03     88
9.      Tom    2017-03-03     12
```

I want to get score avg from 2017-03-03 ~ 2017-03-02 and name as group (Mary,John,Tom)
so, I want the execute ans is ,

```
        name    score
----------------------------------------
1.      Mary    62.5
2.      John    52.5
3.      Tom     31
```

How can I do this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a basic `GROUP BY` query with a `WHERE` clause which restricts to the dates of interest.

```
SELECT name,
       AVG(score) AS score
FROM yourTable
WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-03-02' AND '2017-03-03'
GROUP BY name
```